# How to draw a circle with radius from variable?

Tags: tikz-pgf, variable

I want to draw this simple picture:

[image]

The shapes of points (blue circles) are not important, they are just for example.

The point is that I want to have smth like variable R inside {tikzpicture} drawing the picture. It will give an opportunity to generate automatically different pictures. I've found some examples of using variables, but they are not, what I want.

A pseudocode of what I expect:

```
double R = 10;
coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
coordinate (B) at (-R, 0);
coordinate (C) at (-R, R);
draw (A) circle (R);
draw (B) -- (C); 
fill[blue] (A) circle (1pt);
fill[blue] (B) circle (1pt);
fill[blue] (C) circle (1pt);
```

How can I do that in tex?

Comment: you could use tkz-euclide

Comment: have a look at the answer below

Answer (score 3):

You can use your syntax almost literally except that you have to add backslashes. I also use `circle[radius=R]` instead of `circle (R)`, but the latter would work, too, and use a loop for the blue circles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R = 4;}]
\coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (B) at (-R, 0);
\coordinate (C) at (-R, R);
\draw (A) circle[radius=R];
\draw (B) -- (C); 
\foreach \X in {A,B,C}
{\fill[blue] (\X) circle[radius=1pt];}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, this looks cool! ```declare function={R = 4;}``` - what does it do? Why can we use R now like a number?)

Comment: @Allok Because Ti*k*Z parses these expressions (coordinates, radii, etc), so you can feed them with functions. Such functions can be just constants, as in this case, or more complicated beasts. `\draw (1+R,0) -- ({R*sin(30)},2+1);` also works because the components get parsed.

Comment: But what if I don't want to plug in `{R = 4}` or some expression like you suggest, instead supply a floating point variable computed in a `NewDocumentCommand`? I tried `declare function = {R = \myFp[...]}` without success.

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\R{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (B) at ({-\R}, 0);
\coordinate (C) at (-\R, \R);
\draw (A) circle ({\R});
\draw (B) -- (C); 
\fill[blue] (A) circle (1pt);
\fill[blue] (B) circle (1pt);
\fill[blue] (C) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that's very close, thanks! but in that case R - smth like global variable, is there a way to make it local, only inside {tikzpicture}?

Answer (score 1):

a rough approximation with `tkz-euclide`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    %arbitrary points
    \tkzDefPoint(0,3){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,-3){B}
    %tangent to circle
    %mid point of tangent line
    \tkzDefMidPoint(B,A)\tkzGetPoint{P}
    \tkzDrawLine[add=0.8 and 0](A,P)
    \tkzDrawPoint(P)
    %perpendicular to tangent
    \tkzDefLine[orthogonal =through P](A,B)\tkzGetPoint{X}\tkzDrawPoint(X)
    %draw circle with radius XP
    \tkzDefCircle[through](X,P)
    \tkzDrawCircle(X,P)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way to have a variable for 3 (which you use for A and B) using tikz or tikz-euclide instruments?

Comment: the answer by @rpapa does that